# remove duplicates rows from csv data in tensorflow.js

Tags: python, csv, flatten, tensorflow.js

I am trying to use the tensorflow.js - API to get a model to work which I created in python. Right now I am stuck in the part where I am fetching my data from a csv-File. I am able to fetch the data, but in the python-Code I changed the layout of my data afterwards. I cannot find an example how I would implement this successfully in tensorflow.js
My current data layout:

```
hour----|quit----|mNumber-|sleepSum|difAge--|woman---|paytype-|sum1----|sum2----|sum3----|sum4----|sum5----|sum6----|sum7----|sum8
0-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
1-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
2-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
3-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
4-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
5-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|10------|5
6-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|3-------|2-------|0-------|1-------|10------|7-------|9-------|4
7-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|1-------|3-------|2-------|5-------|3-------|0-------|3-------|1
8-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
9-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
10------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
11------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
12------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
13------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
14------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
15------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
16------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
17------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
18------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|4-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
19------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|4-------|0-------|3-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
20------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|7-------|0-------|3-------|0-------|0-------|2-------|0-------|0
21------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
22------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
23------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
0-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
1-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
2-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
3-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
4-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
5-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
6-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
7-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|2-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
8-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|3-------|9-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|3
9-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|6-------|4-------|1-------|10------|4-------|0-------|0-------|5
10------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|1-------|2-------|0-------|1-------|2-------|0-------|0-------|1
11------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
12------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
13------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
14------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|3
15------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0
16------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
17------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|1
18------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1
19------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0
20------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|2-------|2-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1
21------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|3-------|4-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0
22------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|2-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1
23------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|6-------|1-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|1
```

How I want it to be:

```
hour----|quit----|mNumber-|sleepSum|difAge--|woman---|paytype-|sum1----|sum2----|sum3----|sum4----|sum5----|sum6----|sum7----|sum8----|sum9----|sum10----|...|sum191--|sum192
0-------|0-------|12345---|5-------|50------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0--------|...|0-------|0
0-------|0-------|67890---|40------|37------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0-------|0--------|...|0-------|1
```

So I have redundant data (the first 7 columns are the same for each of the 24 hour-rows. I want to attach the data at the trail, so I come up with 2 lines with my 192 sums for each of the distinct persons.

I wondered if there is a function for rearranging data in tensorflow.js or would you advice to do it manually in a for loop after loading the data from csv?

Right now I am fetching the data like this:

```
const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
  csvUrl,
  {
    hasHeader:false,
    delimiter:';',
    columnNames:['hour','quit','mNumber','sleepSum','difAge','woman','paytype','sum1','sum2','sum3','sum4','sum5','sum6','sum7','sum8']
  });
```

This is how I did it in python

```
data = np.genfromtxt("01TendencyDouble.csv",delimiter=';',dtype=np.dtype(np.int32))
HourData = data[:,7:15]
m = HourData.shape[0]//24
TendencyFull = np.zeros((m,24*8), dtype=int)
MetaData = np.zeros((m,6), dtype=int)    
#Rearrange the Data. Stick all 24 hour-Records of the first 3 Months in a row then those of the sedond 3 months...
for i in range(m):
    Tendency = HourData[i*24:i*24+24,:] 
    TendencyFull[i,:] = Tendency.flatten('F')   
    MetaData[i,0] = data[i*24,1] #MetaData[2,0] is Quit of Record 3
    MetaData[i,1] = data[i*24,2] #MetaData[2,1] is MNumber for Record 3   
    MetaData[i,2] = data[i*24,3] #MetaData[2,2] is Sleep for Record 3           
    MetaData[i,3] = data[i*24,4] #MetaData[2,3] is DifAge for Record 3   
    MetaData[i,4] = data[i*24,5] #MetaData[2,4] is Woman for Record 3   
    MetaData[i,5] = data[i*24,6] #MetaData[2,5] is Paycash for Record 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.data.csv` returns data as a stream using a generator under the hood. The stream itself does not keep a track of the data that was already returned. To keep track of that, each data would need to be stored in a variable.

A generic solution would be to filter if the row is identical to the previous row. For the filtering there is the conditional operator to differentiate case where there are features, labels data from case when there are not (`isLabel` not set)

```
  let latestRow = []
  compareRows = (r1,r2) => {
    const bool = r1.some((x, i) => x !== r2[i])
    console.log(bool)
    return bool
  }

  const flattenedDataset =
    csvDataset
    .filter(r => {
      r = [...(r.ys ? [...Object.values(r.xs), ...Object.values(r.ys)] : Object.values(r))]
      const bool = compareRows(r, latestRow)
      latestRow = r
      return bool
    })
```

If the filtering of duplicates is to be done on a certain time window for instance filter duplicate on each `n` rows, another variable can be used to count the rows. This variable will also be taken into account in the `filter` operator

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I solved the issue by executing the python script I mentioned in my question to convert the data into the desired format. after that, I load the csv-file as mentioned in my question.